# iOS 9 an 10, Bluetooth connection with Bluetooth 3 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I have a request of implementing an iOS application which will be able to communicate with bluetooth device. The chip on that device has Bluetooth 3. The App will be privately distributed, so we don't need AppStore review and we can use anything - the only requirement is, no iPhone jailbreaking. The purpose of the application in reading diagnostic data from the device and sending a few commands to it - like turn left, turn right, setValue - nothing special (it is a special valve, which can be remotely controlled).

Now if a learned correctly the options with using Bluetooth on iOS are:

- **CoreBluetooth:** library for Bluetooth 4.0 LE devices. It cannot be used, because Bluetooth chip is 3.0
- **ExternalAccessory:** the device must be MFI certified, if this option is about to be used. Quite hard that hardware producer will go into the MFI certification, so at the moment not an options.
- **Bluetooth.framework:** private framework which sounded like a good option (I have managed to make it run on iOS9 and iOS10) but the communication with devices on iOS10 does not work anymore. On iOS 9.3.5 on iPhone5 I made it work, but only iOS9 is not an option
- **BTStack:** available via Cydia, but this packages if I have learned correctly require iPhone jailbreaking. Sadly again not an option

The situation clearly does not look good here. I have also read rumors, that it might be possible to use HID bluetooth profile for communication (anyone tried that). is there any C Bluetooth library which could be run on iOS device and work with iOS10?

Thanks for any iadeas.